# Pass parameters from Web Application to CRM Case screen inside Unified Service Desk

Tags: web, dynamics-crm, crm, unified-service-desk

I need to pass parameter from a web application that is opened inside a USD Session to CRM Case Screen that is also opened inside same USD Session.

Is there any possibility to do that? I know how to pass from CRM to web.. But I do not have rights to modify the web application. So how can I pass the values from web to crm?

I just need to put the value from web inside Unified Service Desk Data parameters from there I can have the values inside my CRM page.

Please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Create a new action call where the action is `RunXrmCommand`. The Hosted Control should be the page that is hosting your CRM Case screen. In the "Data" section of the action call, you can simply inject your USD context variable right into the javascript. The data section might look something like this for example:

```
function UpdateCaseFields() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("nwn_name").setValue("[[$Context.CaseName]+]");
}
```

If you are trying to go the other way, you have to fire an event from the javascript. This tutorial provides a good outline of it: https://neilparkhurst.com/2017/04/07/usd-execute-actions-from-javascript/